# The TargetControlID of '%s' is not valid. The value cannot be null or empty

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i am trying to use a `ModalPopupExtender` to popup a `Panel` in ASP.net:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" 
      EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true">

<asp:LinkButton ID="bbShowExport" runat="server" Text="Export"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Panel ID="popupExport" runat="server">
   ...
</asp:Panel>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="popupExtender" runat="server" 
      PopupControlID="popupExport" TargetControlID="bbShowExport">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Meaning that i want `popupExtender` to pop up `popupExport` when the user clicks `bbShowExport`.

When visiting the page there is an error:

> The TargetControlID of 'popupExtender' is not valid. The value cannot be null or empty.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried TargetControlID="popupExport"> ? Without seeing source of ModalPopupExtender it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before your code

```
<Ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Then he would get this exception instead: _"The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it"_

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter. Updated original question to include a mention of the fact that i have a `ToolScriptManager` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgrPopUp" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpePopUpInformation" runat="server" PopupControlID="PanelInfo" TargetControlID="bbShowExport" CancelControlID="btnCloseInfo"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelInfo" runat="server" CssClass="modalpopup">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCloseInfo">×</button>
            <h3>Information</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <fieldset>
                Register Successfully Please Cek Email for Verification
            </fieldset>    
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>

<asp:LinkButton ID="bbShowExport" runat="server" Text="Export"></asp:LinkButton>
```